# What is the syntax for a block comment in the Oz programming language?

Tags: comments, oz

What is the syntax for a block comment in the [Oz programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_(programming_language))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find it in the Oz documentation, but according to the book "Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming" (PETER VAN ROY) this is the syntax:

```
/*
this is a
block
comment
*/
```

Just tried, works perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me in Mozart Engine 2.0.0-alpha.0+build.4091.

Answer (score 1):

Block comment `/* your code, may include LF CR */`

Single line comment `%`

`LF` - line feed,
`CR` - carriage return